# How can I only perform an action once on workflow that starts when an item is changed?

Tags: 2007, workflow, email, designer-workflow, itemupdated

I have a custom workflow that starts whenever an item is changed on a list. It sends an email when someone is added to the People and Groups field. However the email sends **every time** the item is changed.

How can I make it so the email is only sent once on an item?

Answer (score 1):

> Compare the values of your Current Item's Created column and Modified
>   column in your workflow. If the two datetime values are equal, your
>   Current Item is newly created. Else, your Current Item's been changed.

Comment: The problem is, the People and Groups field is empty when the item is created. It is later on filled out by someone else. That's when the email is sent.

Comment: yes you can create send email when item changed for this people and groups field

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, could you explain in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Add a Yes/No check box column to the list with the default entry of 'No' called 'Emailed?'

Add a condition to the workflow before the email action and after your current conditions:

'If/And Current Item: Emailed? is 'No'

Then add a 'Set Field in Current list' action after your email to change if the previous conditions were met.

Step: Step 1
    If value equals value -- (Your Current Conditions)
    and Current Item:Emailed? equals No -- (New Condition)
        Email these users
        Set Emailed? to Yes -- (New Action)